# Программа выдает ошибку(учитывая, что входные данные : 0.1; -1.5; 10 ), код пишу на питоне. Должно выдать Нет корней. Заранее спасибо за помощь)

Tags: python

```
a = float(input()) #код
b = float(input())
c = float(input())
D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
from math import *

x = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
x2 = (-b - sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
if D < 0:
    print("Нет корней")
elif D == 0:
    print(-b / (2 * a))
else:
    print(min(x,x2), max(x, x2), sep="\n")


    Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "jailed_code", line 9, in <module>
        x = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Елизавета, помощь: Python - интерпретатор (я немного упрощаю, но в данном случае - не важно). Это значит, что он выполняет строку за строкой последовательно. Попробуйте теперь ответить, почему у вас программа выдаёт ошибку, а не печатает "нет корней".

Comment: Вы сначала берете корень у оотрицательного числа, потом проверяете на наличие корней

Comment: Спасибо большое, думала на счет неправильности последовательности, но так и не нашла решения, теперь знаю как можно сделать :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну потому что проверять знак `D` нужно до того, как вы пытаетесь из него корень извлечь:

```py
D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
if D < 0:
    print("Нет корней")
elif D == 0:
    print(-b / (2 * a))
else:
    x = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    print(min(x,x2), max(x, x2), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, была такая мысль, но не знала, что строки 7 и 8 можно вставить прямо в условие :)